# How do I redirect/pipe all of my terminal shell script's output into another program from within the script?

Tags: bash

I have a script where I want to do the equivalent of this:

> myscript | anotherprogram

but from within the script. I don't want to invoke

> mysubtask | anotherprogram

*each time* I have to run my subtasks in my script, I just want the filter started and all my OUT & ERR routed to it (the script is not interactive).

So in the end what I want to do is

1. Set the OUT & ERR to the input of anotherprogram. anotherprogram will only run for one instance of the script so that all of my output goes to it.
2. Run the rest of my script as normal with the OUT & ERR of my subsequent echos and subtask outputs going to anotherprogram continuously (I only want anotherprogram to run once, that is during the whole rest of my script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two simple ways I can see to achieve this.  First, you could use a subshell with parentheses:

```
(
  echo hello
  echo world
) 2>&1 | anotherprogram
```

or you could use `exec` to redirect the various file descriptors at the top of your script

```
exec > >( anotherprogram ) # send stdout to anotherprogram
exec 2>&1                  # merge stderr into stdout

echo hello
echo world
```

Comment: Which one results in fewer forks?

Comment: On my system (Mac OS X, zsh 5.0.0), there is two forks in the first case, zero in the second.

Comment: I guess the latter (just forking `anotherprogram` rather than the subshell as well), though you could also try using `{ ... }` instead of `( ... )` to group the commands without having to spawn a subshell.

Comment: I think the two redirections in the version with `exec` need to happen in the opposite order to have the intended effect. (?)

Comment: @JonO you are correct, I always get mixed up with the fact that you have to say `> file 2>&1` but `2>&1 | command`

Comment: Yes, same here. (For the benefit of future readers I should note that my comment was on a previous version, and the order as it appears in the post now is the *right* one)...

Comment: @abeaumet There have been some edits. Do you mean the `()`, `{}` or `exec` method?

Comment: By my measure in bash `exec` and `{}` seem to create the same number of forks.

Comment: @CyberSkull I mean the () method